# How to determine where the mouse is hovering relative to a parent element

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing drag/drop for a treeview where I'm supporting drag/drop.

The tree has folders and files in it.  When I drag over the bottom 25% of the folder, I want it to reorder.  When I drag over the top 75% of the treeviewitem, I want it to drop the content *into* the folder.

How do I determine where I am in the element?  Here is my attempt that doesn't work:

```
    private bool ShouldReorder(TreeViewItem targetItem)
    {
        var relativePosition = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(targetItem));
        return relativePosition.Y/targetItem.ActualHeight < 0.25;
    }
```

This code has relative positions that are negative.

Answer (score 1):

after converting it to screen coordinates you could convert it back to client coordinates for the parent control

```
Parent.PointToClient(screenpt) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to consume global mouse events (this code can also get global x/y position data regardless of window focus):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

for my program at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/347795/Inactivity-Logoff